# Applying custom style on ticks of Highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to apply custom style on xAis ticks of Highcharts. I want to style ticks in the form of circle instead of line.
 like `ticks.chart.renderer.cirlce();`

Not able to find a way to get it done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap `getMatkPath` function, to render another tick, see: http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/83/

```
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Tick.prototype, 'getMarkPath', function (prev, x, y, tickLength, tickWidth, horiz, renderer) {
    return renderer.circle(x, y, tickLength);
});
```

### Edit:

When using zoom/panning etc from Highcharts or Highstock, it is required to returned data from `getMarkPath` is array of path (`d` for SVG).

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/AVhaL/1/

### Update: (2016-01-28):

In Highcharts 4.2.x new method is required (we should return path for tickmark, not the rendered object):

```
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Tick.prototype, 'getMarkPath', function(prev, x, y, tickLength, tickWidth, horiz, renderer) {
  return renderer.symbol('circle', x - tickLength / 2, y - tickLength / 2, tickLength, tickLength);
});
```

Comment: In case of highstock charts if range is selected dynamically, then circles don't retain their positions. how to get the same thing working.  refer this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AVhaL/

Comment: yeah, it works great. Thanks.
but I was wondering about how to set attributes like fill color.

Comment: Just overwrite `tick.render` like previos function. See: http://jsfiddle.net/AVhaL/2/

Comment: thanks, one last thing which I am not able to figure out.
I want to attach mouseover event to these ticks. So that on mouseover ticks get zoomed in and concetric circle gets drawn within with filled in some other color.
I tried out this.ticks.element.onmouseover but I saw it is been set to null.

Comment: It should work. Could you create example what have you tried?

Comment: Hi, how to draw another concentric circle within circular ticks. which should be visible on mouseover. ?

Comment: You need to write this on your own, it's not built-in feature. USer renderer: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.circle