# Highcharts: Add dots to series and style between empty data points

Tags: javascript, highcharts

there is two things I'd like to do with this chart http://jsfiddle.net/4vyaaLjL/

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'area',
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Fruit consumption *'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Oranges', 'Bananas', 'Grapes', 'Plums', 'Strawberries', 'Raspberries']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Y-Axis'
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.value;
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [0, 1, 4, 4, 5, 2, 3, 7]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [1, 0, 3, null, 3, 1, 2, 1]
    }]
});
```

1. I'd like to style the 'null' data point with dashes.
2. Have some styled dots in place of the squares in the image.

[image: HighCharts]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. There is an option `connectNulls`, but you can not style with a different dash-style. So how about using [`series.zones`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.zones)? Unfortunately, you need to calculate in advance, where should be zones according to the null data-points. Another solution for this is to simple create separate series with just two points and line between them. You can connect two series using `series.linkedTo` option.
2. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21136568/applying-custom-style-on-ticks-of-highchart).

And demo with 4.2.x version: http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/504/